Is it true that p-integrable function can be written as a convolution of an integrable function and p-integrable function?
We know that convolution of an integrable function with an $p$-integrable is an $p$-integrable function. This follows from Young's inequality.
My question: Is it true that $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)*L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

It’s certainly not true for $p=\infty$ since the convolution of an $L^p$ and $L^q$ function (where $p,q$ are Holder duals) is continuous but not every $L^\infty$ function is continuous.

This is discussed in Edwin Hewitt, The ranges of certain convolution operators, Math. Scand. 15 (1964), 147–155.

Does $L^p(\mathbb R^n) * L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ mean the set of convolutions, or the span of the set of convolutions?

Thank you very much @Hjalmar Rosengren. It was very much helpful.
